# Copy data from form into cell in Excel 2010

Tags: forms, excel, vba

I currently have an Excel 2010 spreadsheet. I have designed a form and I'm looking to allow users to enter date into the form and it then be entered into the worksheet.

My first entry is "txtDate" on my form and I wish for this to be entered into cell J7 with the next data in the form "txtTime" going into cell K7 and then other data into other cells in the row - L7, M7, N7 etc etc... Once this cell is submitted with a button using on the form, the data is entered and then the next time the form is used, the data will go into the next row below, row 8 and then row 9 on the next occasion etc...

I've found the sample below code on the internet and the example shows that it starts in cell A2. I can't see mention of A2 and so I'm wondering how I edit the code to start in cell J7.

```
'Copy input values to sheet.
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Animals")
    lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    With ws
        .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = Me.cboClass.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 2).Value = Me.txtGivenName.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 3).Value = Me.txtTagNumber.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 4).Value = Me.txtSpecies.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 5).Value = Me.cboSex.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 6).Value = Me.cboConservationStatus.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 7).Value = Me.txtComment.Value
```

Here is my code dated 27/03/2015 following the answer:

```
Dim lRow As Long
     Dim ws As Worksheet
     Set ws = Worksheets("Pursue")
     lRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row, 7)

     With ws
          .Cells(lRow, 10).Value = Me.dateBox.Value
          etc....
```

Comment: As  I mentioned in my answer you need to change the column count to 10, if J is the column you want to find the last cell in, in other words, the line where you set the value of `lRow` needs to be `lRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row, 7)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.Cells(lRow, 1).Value` (and so forth) is what references what cell is written to. The first argument says what row the cell is in, the second what column it is in. When referencing the cells explicitly I see little reason to do it this way though, it is mainly for when you'd make a loop where e.g. `lRow` was incremented by one for each iteration in order to write down a column.

Since `lRow` is decided using `lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row` it will always be the number of the first empty row in column A. To change it to return the first empty row in column J, you need to change the 1 in `Cells` to 10 (J is the 10th letter in the alphabet. To get it to not start further up than row 7 at any time, I'd add in a `Max`-statement:

```
lRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row, 7)
```

To get the sub to write to column J onwards inside the `With`-statement, you need to change the column-references to reflect this. Currently it writes to column 1, 2, 3, etc. you want it to write to column 10, 11, 12, etc. I.e. something like:

```
With ws
    .Cells(lRow, 10).Value = Me.cboClass.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 11).Value = Me.txtGivenName.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 12).Value = Me.txtTagNumber.Value
    etc.
```

Comment: my apologies. I mixed up my numbers and letters. I've reflected my original post. So the form entries should fill cells in a ROW, not a column and then on next use, fill the next row etc.. My apologies again

Comment: @pnuts Hmm, yeah, now that you mention it, that is a worksheet-function, isn't it? Edited the code in the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to enter the values in the correct row / column however when I open the form and add a second entry, it writes over the same row.

Comment: @thefragileomen Are you sure you have the `.Offset(0,1)` part in the line where you set a new value for `lRow`? And are you sure that `lRow` is set to a new value every time you use the form? Is `lRow` set using the correct column?

Comment: Thanks @eirikdaude. I've edited my question with my amended code following your advice. So cell J7 is my starting cell and this will contain a date value. This column will also have a value so I want to move onto J8 and the next one down etc